# What is this connector name used on the NordicTrack RW200?

Tags: power-electronics, identification, connector

I need this exact connector, but I can't find it. It's used on the NordicTrack RW200. The female is about 8 x 10 x 20 millimetres.

I looked at : https://helpful.knobs-dials.com/index.php/Common_plugs_and_connectors

[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: that looks like an SM2 Female plug... can you post the inside of it?

Comment: Added a new picture

Comment: You could always buy a connector set, cut the old ones off, and put the new ones on.

Comment: I would prefer to use the original connector as most people will find the procedure too hard.

Comment: @Naster check my post answer, and check your male plug is it 5mm in width? and the pin plug is a bit to the top? and this pin using 2.5mm pitch

Comment: does the red connector plug into the pink one?

Comment: Yes the red goes into the pink connector.

Answer (score 2):

If the pins are 0.025" square and on 0.100" centers, then AMP MTE (crimp) or MTA (IDC - insulation displacement) series.  Molex and just about everybody has an itermateable part.

Here is the AMP IDC part for #22 wire:

https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/te-connectivity-amp-connectors/3-641653-2/765829

Answer (score 1):

With added picture, it is SM2 plug connector.

From: [This link](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32754343668.html)
[image: This is SM2 Plug connector in front]

From: [this link](https://jetacon-sz-com.sell.everychina.com/p-106446819-jst-sm2-54-2-54mm-connector-housing-header-terminals-for-led-strip-power-supply.html)
[image: width]

[image: front]
From: [this link](https://www.adafruit.com/product/2880)

but the SM2 plug pin is a bit to the top, it could fit.

If it doesn't fit The NordicTrack using a non-standard SM2 plug. just change the plug entrirely.

Comment: The ones in the picture above seem to be lacking the "wings" on one side of the connector.